# multi dimension array split with explode PHP

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist

i have multidimension array

```
$a = "5,add|4,edit|6,add|6,edit|19,add|19,delete|19,view";
```

then i explode $a

```
$array_a = explode("|", $a);

//loop

for($i=0;$i<=count($arr_a)-1;$i++){

    arr_b = explode(",", $arr_a[$i]);

    foreach($arr_b as $id => $access){
        echo $id." have access ".$access;
    }
}

//result 
0 have access 5
1 have access add
0 have access 4
1 have access edit
0 have access 6
1 have access add
0 have access 6
1 have access edit
0 have access 19
1 have access add
0 have access 19
1 have access delete
0 have access 19
1 have access view
//-end result
```

the problem is :

how i can make the result like this

5 have access add
4 have access edit
6 have access add,edit
19 have access add,delete,view

Comment: Why did you use a for loop to iterate through `$arr_a` and then a foreach to iterate through `$arr_b`. Why not just use a foreach for both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one (tested):

```
// intial data
$strAccess = "5,add|4,edit|6,add|6,edit|19,add|19,delete|19,view";

// build access array
$arrayAccess = array();

$tmpList = explode('|', $strAccess);

foreach($tmpList as $access)
{
  list($idUser, $right) = explode(',', $access);

  if (!isset($arrayAccess[$idUser]))
    $arrayAccess[$idUser] = array();

  $arrayAccess[$idUser][] = $right;
}

// print it out
foreach($arrayAccess as $idUser => $accessList)
  echo $idUser." has access ".implode(",", $accessList)."\n";
```

Comment: i can believe this code! very amazing! it helped me, thx brother!

Answer (score 2):

I think Regex would be a better solution in this case, in case you haven't considered using it.

**Sample (Tested):**

```
$a = "5,add|4,edit|6,add|6,edit|19,add|19,delete|19,view";

$result = array();

// match each pair in the input
if (preg_match_all('/(\\d+)\\,(.*?)(\\||$)/m', $a, $matches)){

    foreach( $matches[1] as $match_index => $match ){

        $result[$match][] = $matches[2][$match_index];

    }

}

// loop through the results and print in desired format
foreach( $result as $entry_index => $entry ){
    echo "$entry_index have access " . implode( ',', $entry ) . "\n";
}
```

output:

```
5 have access add
4 have access edit
6 have access add,edit
19 have access add,delete,view
```

Using regex simplifies the code and also makes it somewhat easier to change the format of the input that is supported.

The $result array ended up with a hash map using your numeric ids as the keys and arrays of permissions (add, delete, etc) as the value for each key.

Comment: I'm not sure that a Regex significantly simplifies things / helps maintainability here, against the "two explode" solution I've suggested... Rather a matter of taste IMO. At least, unlike a lot of other proposed solutions, this one is clear enough and **works** :) +1

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = "5,add|4,edit|6,add|6,edit|19,add|19,delete|19,view";
$array_a = explode("|". $a);

//loop
$aRights = array();
for($i=0;$i<=count($arr_a)-1;$i++){ $arr_b = explode(",", $arr_a[$i]);

     foreach($arr_b as $id => $access){
        $aRights[$id][] = $access;
     }
}

foreach( $aRights as $id=>$rightsList){
    echo $id." have access ";
    $i=1;
    foreach($rightsList as $r){

       echo $r;
       if($i != count($rightsList)) echo ",";
       $i++;
   }
}
```

Comment: `$aRights[id]` will certainly throw an "undefined constant" warning.

Comment: i just try it, but it have blank result.. could somebody help me to get this matter solved?

Comment: Did you include the orginal string? Thats not in there... I just added it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use counter something like

```
  $count5=0;
  foreach($arr_b as $id => $access){
    if($access=='5'){
    $count5++;
    }
  echo $id." have access ".$count5;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

What about something like hashmapping:

```
$tobegenerated = array();
$a = explode(yourdelimiter,yourstring);
foreach ($a as $cur)
{
    $b = explode(delimiter,$cur);
    $tobegenerated[$cur[0]] = $cur[1];
}
//Print hashmap $tobegenerated
```

This should work, remember that in php arrays are also hash maps

**Edit 1:**
Arrays in PHP are hash maps. A hash map can be interpreted as an array where keys can be anything and value can be anything too. In this case, you would like to use a hash map because you need to bind values that are "outside" the range of the array (even if they are ints). So a hash map is exactly what you want, allowing to specify anything as a key.

How a [hash map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) work is something that you can search on google or on wikipedia. How arrays work in php can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: i dont get it cant explain more details?

Comment: See my edit, there is an explaination. You can find examples of arrays on PHP array page that I've linked.